# Google App Script で自作の関数を呼び出し時にエラー: 引数が無効です

Tags: google-apps-script

A2からB11のセルの中身を削除し、終わったらA2のセルをアクティブな状態にするスクリプトが動きません。

"引数が無効です" というエラーが出て、下記の関数が実行されません。

どなたか構文の誤り等分かる方がいたら教えてください

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートアプリを開く
  var sheet3 = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付けシート'), true);
  //sheet3でURL貼り付けシートを指定
  sheet3.getRange('A2:B11').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  sheet3.getRange('A2').activate();
  //URL貼り付けシートのA2からB11のセルの中身を削除し、終わったらA2のセルをアクティブな状態にする
  //10社入力が済んだら、黄色いセル内を削除するためのスクリプト
};
```

Comment: `引数が無効ですというエラーが出て、下記マクロが実行されません。`について、エラーが発生する具体的な箇所を示すことで他のユーザが問題を考える助けになるかと思いました。

Comment: どこでエラーが出ているのかも現状わからないため、検証してみます
実行ログ
13:17:16 お知らせ 実行開始
13:17:17 エラー 
Exception: Invalid argument
myFunction @ マクロ.gs:4

実行時のログはこのように表示されます

Comment: var sheet3 = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付けシート'), true);
４行目がこれなので、この構文のどこかに誤りがあるのだろうと思います

Comment: コメントありがとうございました、どうやら構文ではなくシート名に誤りがあったようでした

Answer (score 0):

シート3を用意して、名前をURL貼り付けシートにして実行してください。

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  var sheet3 = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付けシート'), true);
  sheet3.getRange('A2:B11').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  sheet3.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、コピーして貼り付けて、シートの名前もURL貼り付けシートにしているのですが、引数が無効ですというエラーが表示されてしまいます

他にも同じマクロ内に別のスクリプトを3つほど用意しているのですが、このスクリプトと２つ目のスクリプトだけが実行できなくて、３つ目と４つ目は実行される状況です。

スクリプトの割り当て直しを行っても同じエラーが出ました。
他のスクリプトが問題を起こしている可能性もあったりするでしょうか？

Comment: var sheet3 = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付けシート'), true);
どうやらこの部分でエラーが起きているようなんですよね

Comment: 改めてシート名を確認すると、どうやらシート名にスペースが入っていたため動かないようでした
ご回答いただきありがとうございました。